# AFNetworking reachability listener across entire app

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I need to have offline capability in my app, so I allow the user to create certain objects to offline if there is no connection. Then when there is a connection again I upload the data to my server.

Currently I just check for reachability in `applicationDidBecomeActive` and then upload the data, but I would prefer to also know when my app is back online so that I can upload it then as well.

**Using `AFNetworking 2`, is it possible to have a "global" reachability monitor or notification, so that I can know when the app is back online so I can upload?**

Comment: Not directly with AFN, but you could use something like [FXReachability](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXReachability) or Tony Million's [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) wrapped in a singleton (or just using the NSNotification example) to listen for network change events.

Answer (score 1):

Add the AFNetworkReachabilityManager to your app delegate, and use following:

```
[AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            DDLogDebug(@"Not reachable");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
             AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            DDLogDebug(@"Reachable");
            break;
        default:
            DDLogDebug(@"Unknown status!");
            break;
    }
}];
```

Comment: But how would this help to get a notification anywhere in the app?

Comment: your app delegate "lives" through the life of your app...whenever your app is reachable again you'll get notification in your app delegate...your question was:  is it possible to have a "global" reachability monitor or notification.. the  code I posted above is what you asked for, if you have a more specific question I would be happy to answer.